# Adding an element to an XML-document with a previously newly created string from an attribute node

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, xpath

This is my first post here. Thanks a mil for having me around and sorry if I make mistakes or create misunderstandings in this first effort. My conundrum is as follows:
I wrote a small script for updating some third party software components, which requires changing an XML file having the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>xxx</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>xxx</OutputType>
    <StartupObject>xxx</StartupObject>
    <RootNamespace>xxx</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>xxx</AssemblyName>
    <FileAlignment>xxx</FileAlignment>
    <MyType>WindowsFormsWithCustomSubMain</MyType>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>
    </TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <SccProjectName>xxx</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>xxx</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>xxx</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>xxx</SccProvider>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
...
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="someString, Version=123, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ab1, processorArchitecture=xxx">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
```

The function in question takes a substring from the attribute include and should ideally add it to a newly created XML element, (i.e. `<HintPath>xyz</HintPath>`). Selecting the attribute and getting the string worked once I got around the Namespace issue (thanks to StackOverflow). However, when I am about to add the HintPath-element using AppendChild, I get an error saying that the object is not correctly referenced. I tried to use LINQ to resolve the issue, but could not get around the query Syntax (since I am used to using XPath). If somebody has a LINQ solution, please do let me know.

This is my Code so far (XPath Approach)

```vb
 Private Function getAttributInclude(ByVal path2xml As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        Dim listAttributValues As New List(Of String)
        Dim nodeAttributInsertValueSplitted() As String
        Dim splittedStringMitEndungDll As String
        Dim nsmanager As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable)
        nsmanager.AddNamespace("msn", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003")
        nsmanager.AddNamespace(String.Empty, "urn:test") 'default namespace

        xmlDoc.Load(path2xml)


        Dim nodeListAttributInclude As XmlNodeList
        Dim root As XmlElement = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
        nodeListAttributInclude = root.SelectNodes("/Project/ItemGroup/Reference/@Include")
        Dim nodeAttributeInclude As XmlNode
        Dim hintPath As XmlElement
        For Each nodeAttributeInclude In nodeListAttributInclude
            nodeAttributInsertValueSplitted = nodeAttributeInclude.Value.Split(",")
            splittedStringMitEndungDll = String.Format("..\..\lib\{0}.dll", nodeAttributInsertValueSplitted(0))
            listAttributValues.Add(nodeAttributeInclude.InnerText)
            hintPath = xmlDoc.CreateElement("HintPath", nodeAttributeInclude.NamespaceURI)
            hintPath.InnerText = splittedStringMitEndungDll
            nodeAttributeInclude.ParentNode.AppendChild(hintPath)
        Next
        xmlDoc.Save(path2xml)

        Return listAttributValues
```

I wonder particularly why .AppendChild is not working in this case

Thanks a mil in advance for any help provided.

Dear all

Just would like to give you an update. 
I got back to the project and was provided with a good approach. However it turned out to be just one step in the right direction and I might be to blame for not having explicitly written what I intended with the original. The new snippet is as follows:
    Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(path2xml)

```
    Dim nsmanager As New XmlNamespaceManager(New NameTable)

    nsmanager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003")
    nsmanager.AddNamespace(String.Empty, "urn:test") 'default namespace

    Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"

    Dim xAttr = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//ns:Reference", nsmanager).Attribute("Include").Value

    Dim hpElement As New XElement(New XElement(ns + "HintPath", xAttr))

    xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//ns:Reference", nsmanager).Add(hpElement)

    xDoc.Save(path2xml)
```

So far the XML element is being created accordingly. However, using the Xpath-expression I thought I would get all elements having the attribute I am looking for. Moreover, I initially would have liked to get a nodelist since I am going to apply replacements on the attribute string for each node / element that contains the attribute. It turned out that only the first element is selected using your suggestion.
here are my new questions:
1.Is it possible to select all  nodes using this Syntax?
2. How would I go about carrying out the string replacement(s) in each attribute node
Please refer to my initial post, showing you my initial idea using a node list and iterating over each node for the replacements (this Approach worked, but I could not create the XML-HintPath-element in the end). I guess I got confused along the way due to my lack of programming experience, sorry about that
Would be grand if you or anyone else could shed some more light on this topic.

Update:
I had another go at the code and there is one thing that I do not understand at all: Having re-examined each line in the code block above, I came across the following line:

```
xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//ns:Reference", nsmanager).Add(hpElement)
```

The description of parameters and return values said that a single value would be retrived. I admit that I missed reading that particular info beforehand. However, I saw that a plural version, i.e. XPathSelectElements was also possible. According to my understanding that seemed like a good Approach (and a slight but all too typical typo). Much to my surprise when changing the line to

```
xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//ns:Reference", nsmanager).Add(hpElement)
```

I got an error saying that

```
Attribute is not a member of System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Xml.Linq.XElement
```

This is exactly what I do not understand. How can selecting all elements be wrong? And how is it posssible to get a List of all nodes selected by the XPAth Expression for further processing? I am quite at a loss now. Looking Forward to your replies.

I tried the following approaches found in this and other Forums.

```
Dim xAttr = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//ns:Reference", nsmanager).Attribute("Include").Value

Dim xAttr = xDoc.Root.Descendants("Reference").Attributes("Include")

Dim xAttr = xDoc.XPathEvaluate("//Reference/@Include")
```

However, none of these approaches seem to work. I cannot select the attribute-string and perform the substitutions accordingly. Maybe this helps in identifying the Problem.

Update:
I took another look at my previous code and was able to resolve some issues (cf. code posted below). I can now select all nodes I had envisaged. Moreover, in Debug-mode the replacements also seem to kick in. However, and this is really starting to annoy me, I cannot figure out how to add the new with some of the replaced strings. The example provided by Microsoft

```
uses XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
```

What I would like to do aacomplish us using the already existing Xpath Expression for the element . While trying that I ususally get an error that the Object 'x' cannot be converted into to Object 'y'. Could somebody please help me out resolving this issue?

This is the new code

```
Private Function getAttributInclude(ByVal pfad2xml As String) As XmlDocument

Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument
xDoc.Load(pfad2xml)

Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"

Dim nsmanager As New XmlNamespaceManager(New NameTable)

nsmanager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003")
nsmanager.AddNamespace(String.Empty, "urn:test") 

Dim navigator As XPathNavigator = xDoc.CreateNavigator()

Dim xpathAttributInclude As XPathExpression = XPathExpression.Compile("//ns:Reference/ns:SpecificVersion/../@Include")

xpathAttributInclude.SetContext(nsmanager)

Dim xpathElementSpecificVersion As XPathExpression = XPathExpression.Compile("//ns:Reference/ns:SpecificVersion")
xpathElementSpecificVersion.SetContext(nsmanager)

Dim nodeListAttributInclude As XPathNodeIterator = navigator.Select(xpathAttributInclude)
Dim nodeListElementSpecificVersion As XPathNodeIterator = navigator.Select(xpathElementSpecificVersion)

Dim hintPath As XmlElement

For Each nodeAttributInclude In nodeListAttributInclude
    Dim nodeAttributInsertValueSplitted = nodeAttributInclude.Value.Split(",")
    Dim replacedNodeText As String
    Dim splittedStringMitEndungDll
    Dim replacedVersionAttribut As String

    replacedNodeText = nodeAttributInsertValueSplitted(0).ToString.Replace( _
        txtBoxEnterVersionNummerOld.Text, txtBoxEnterVersionNummerNew.Text)

    writeLog(replacedNodeText + vbCrLf)

    splittedStringMitEndungDll = String.Format("..\..\lib\{0}.dll", replacedNodeText)

    writeLog(splittedStringMitEndungDll + vbCrLf)

    If tbXmlDevExpressVersionNew.Text.Length > 0 Then
        Dim splittedElementSpecificVersion = nodeAttributInsertValueSplitted(1).Split("=")

        replacedVersionAttribut = splittedElementSpecificVersion(1).ToString.Replace( _
                splittedElementSpecificVersion(1).ToString, tbXmlDevExpressVersionNew.Text)

        writeLog(replacedVersionAttribut + vbCrLf)
    Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid version numbers")
    End If

    hintPath = xDoc.CreateElement("HintPath", nodeAttributInclude.NamespaceURI)
    hintPath.InnerText = splittedStringMitEndungDll

    Dim node2insertAfter = xDoc.DocumentElement

    For Each nodeElementSpecificVersion In nodeListElementSpecificVersion
        xDoc.InsertAfter(hintPath, node2insertAfter.SelectSingleNode("//Reference/SpecificVersion"))
        writeLog(nodeElementSpecificVersion.ToString + vbCrLf)
    Next

Next

xDoc.Save("c:\tmp\result_xml.xml")

Return xDoc
End Function
```

Update:
I came across an [interesting article](http://geekswithblogs.net/pakistan/archive/2005/08/23/50883.aspx) that provided one strep towards a solution. However, I am still having the issue that the element in question is only appended to very last item, although I am using a loop in a loop. Moreover, the replacements do not seem to take effect, either. Here is a snippet of the adjusted appendChild section for adding the XML elements

```
For Each nodeElementReference In nodeListElementReference
                Dim node2StartInsert = DirectCast(nodeElementReference, System.Xml.IHasXmlNode).GetNode
                node2StartInsert.AppendChild(hintPath)
            Next
```

Thanks a mil in advance for your assisstance.

Kind regards
Sas

I managed to find a solution. However, the code only needed to extract the Attribute, which is now correctly in the Input XML this code is applied to. Using both XMLElement and XPathNavigator provided the means of writing the additional element to the existing XML file.

```
Dim hintPath As XmlElement
    Dim nodeAttributInclude As XPathNavigator

    For Each nodeAttributInclude In nodeListAttributInclude
        Dim nodeAttributInsertValueSplitted = nodeAttributInclude.Value.Split(",")


        Dim versionsInfoText As String
        Dim splittedStringMitEndungDll


        versionsInfoText = nodeAttributInsertValueSplitted(0).ToString


        splittedStringMitEndungDll = String.Format("..\..\lib\{0}.dll", versionsInfoText)


        nodeAttributInclude.MoveToParent()


        hintPath = xDoc.CreateElement("HintPath")
        hintPath.InnerText = splittedStringMitEndungDll


        nodeAttributInclude.AppendChild("<HintPath>" + hintPath.InnerText + "</HintPath>")
    Next

    xDoc.Save("c:\tmp\result_xml.xml")
```

Comment: Update: I did some checking and found out that the XPath notations appear not to be evaluated. I tried the relative and absolute path Notation. However selecting only //@Include resulted in a nodelist as expected. I am not sure, but I gather the XPath implementation might be broken. Would be Grand if anybody could add an Explanation.

Comment: Somebody pointed out that it was not clear which document(s) were my source and target file. The Input file is the XML posted here. The output file is supposed to be same but with the additional XML element added to it (<Reference> should thus get another child item called <HintPath>, which in turn contains the modified substring). I hope this helps for further discussions

Comment: To be more precise about the error. The issue is that  "System.Xml.XmlNodeList" cannot be converted into "System.Xml.XmlNode". The question is how should I get to the nodes that are required for finding the correct position for InsertAfter if not using a node list. I also thought that the loop would take care of that. I am quite confused and at a loss now.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution. However, the code only needed to extract the Attribute, which is now correctly in the Input XML this code is applied to. Using both XMLElement and XPathNavigator provided the means of writing the additional element to the existing XML file. 
Dim hintPath As XmlElement
    Dim nodeAttributInclude As XPathNavigator

```
For Each nodeAttributInclude In nodeListAttributInclude
    Dim nodeAttributInsertValueSplitted = nodeAttributInclude.Value.Split(",")


    Dim versionsInfoText As String
    Dim splittedStringMitEndungDll


    versionsInfoText = nodeAttributInsertValueSplitted(0).ToString


    splittedStringMitEndungDll = String.Format("..\..\lib\{0}.dll", versionsInfoText)


    nodeAttributInclude.MoveToParent()


    hintPath = xDoc.CreateElement("HintPath")
    hintPath.InnerText = splittedStringMitEndungDll


    nodeAttributInclude.AppendChild("<HintPath>" + hintPath.InnerText + "</HintPath>")
Next

xDoc.Save("c:\tmp\result_xml.xml")
```